# Display an image from external url using phonegap/jquery for android

Tags: jquery, android, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am trying to display an image from external url like below using phonegap/jquery for android app but getting application error as "connection to the server was unsuccessful"

img src="http://www.techinasia.com/techinasia/wp-content/uploads/2009/12/Search.jpg"

Please anyone help on this.

Comment: hi, now i am getting question mark instead of proper image

Answer (score 5):

When you're generating the whitelist links, make sure there's no slash "/" at the end of the url.

```
<access origin="http://google.com" /> <!--  this works -->
<access origin="http://google.com/" /> <!-- this doesn't -->
```

In my case I was getting the question marks because of this, hope this could be helpful for someone else in the future

Answer (score 4):

You need to put the external website on the whitelist.
See how to here:
http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.9.0/guide_whitelist_index.md.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<a href="#"><img src="http://www.techinasia.com/techinasia/wp-content/uploads/2009/12/Search.jpg"  data-rel="external"/></a>
```

Comment: thanks for the reply but i am getting question mark in the place of image. please look into....

Answer (score 0):

In the onCreate method of the class that extends DroidGap you'll want to increase the timeout of loading the HTML file so you can get the remote image. Add...

```
super.setIntegerProperty("loadUrlTimeoutValue", 60000);
```

to your onCreate method.

Comment: thanks for the reply but i am getting question mark in the place of image. please look into....

Comment: ya i tried this approach too, but still getting question mark instead of image, may i know is any permission or any config setting required to access image from external url

Answer (score 0):

One other possible problem is that you did not put the URL (domain) of the image source into the phonegap.plist file.

Answer (score 0):

Just cut the size of the image using any image compressor and use only `.jpg` images.